# Per Frame Buffers

Tags: buffers, frames, osx

How to make buffers accessible only from one frame(window) and not accessible from another and vice versa? So I want to have each frame with its own buffers.

I'm on OS X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can think of is launching a new instance of Emacs instead of opening a new frame normally. You can set `C-x 5 2` to start `emacs` instead of creating a new frame:

```
(defun start-other-emacs ()
  "Start another Emacs process to open an independent Emacs window."
  (interactive)
  ;;; Run the command "emacs", piping output into a 
  ;;; buffer called "*other-emacs*"
  (start-process "emacs" "*other-emacs*" "emacs"))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x 5 2") 'start-other-emacs)
```

Unfortunately, this isn't terribly fast unless you have a more optimized Emacs config than I do!

Comment: Thanks, good enough for me. I guess, then it was more a question how to open second Emacs Instance on OS X. For those who'll come up with same question: Launching it from command line via `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs` is the way

Answer (score 6):

Generally you can't have frame-local list of buffers. It might have been possible when `buffer-alist` was exposed at Lisp level (but even like that I'm not too sure), but that possibility is now gone.

The next best thing is to pretend you do. Packages like [perspective.el](https://github.com/nex3/perspective-el) can help in this regard: they avoid presenting buffers that are not "contained" in the current perspective.
You can then activate different perspectives in different frames to implement your scenario.

Comment: Cheers, for pointing at `perspective`

Comment: This version of perspective is even better: github.com/Bad-ptr/persp-mode.el

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear (to me, at least). Just what do you mean by "*accessible*"? (displayed without selecting? selected as current buffer?) And what do you mean here by "*and vice versa*"? And what does "*each frame with its own buffers*" (plural?) mean?

Taking a wild guess, perhaps you mean that you want a single buffer (not two or more) shown in each frame.  And perhaps you want the frame to show only that buffer.  (No, I realize that this is not at all what you said.  But what you said is anyway unclear to me.)

If so, then to use a separate frame by default for most buffer-displaying commands, try setting option `pop-up-frames` to `t`.  (Or customize the complex option `display-buffer-alist`.)  And to prevent other buffers from being shown in the same frame, make the buffer's window dedicated -- see the Elisp manual, node `Dedicated Windows`.

But if you do only those things then you will wind up somewhat disappointed, as Emacs does not always behave well with one-buffer-per-frame.

If you want a relatively coherent setup that provides one-buffer-per-frame behavior, consider trying [One On One Emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/OneOnOneEmacs).  Try library [oneonone.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/oneonone.el), for example.  To make all windows dedicated you can customize `special-display-regexps` so that it matches all buffer names.  (Or again, you can fiddle with customizing option `display-buffer-alist`.)

Answer (score 0):

There is also [frame-purpose](https://github.com/alphapapa/frame-purpose.el):

> makes it easy to open purpose-specific frames that only show certain buffers, e.g. by buffers’ major mode, their filename or directory, etc, with custom frame/X-window titles, icons, and other frame parameters.